# Convert WebsiteField to emailField

Tags: php, email

**Seeking to convert this .php page (that works) with the website input to an email input**

I have changed all the websiteField items to emailField including an email Regex but it brings back a error message from the server. *500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.*

```
    <?php

    require "config.php";
    require "connect.php";

    if(isset($_POST['submitform']) && isset($_POST['txn_id']))
    {
    $_POST['nameField'] = esc($_POST['nameField']);
    $_POST['websiteField'] =  esc($_POST['websiteField']);
    $_POST['messageField'] = esc($_POST['messageField']);

    $error = array();

    if(mb_strlen($_POST['nameField'],"utf-8")<2)
    {
        $error[] = 'Please fill in a valid name.';
    }

    if(mb_strlen($_POST['messageField'],"utf-8")<2)
    {
        $error[] = 'Please fill in a longer message.';
    }

    if(!validateURL($_POST['websiteField']))
    {
        $error[] = 'The URL you entered is invalid.';
    }

    $errorString = '';
    if(count($error))
    {
        $errorString = join('<br />',$error);
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO dc_comments (transaction_id, name, url, message)
                        VALUES (
                            '".esc($_POST['txn_id'])."',
                            '".$_POST['nameField']."',
                            '".$_POST['websiteField']."',
                            '".$_POST['messageField']."'
                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            $messageString = '<a href="donate.php">You were added to our donor list! &raquo;</a>';
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Thank you!</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body class="thankyouPage">

<div id="main">
    <h1>Thank you!</h1>
    <h2>Add Yourself to our Donor List. </h2>

    <div class="lightSection">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="nameField">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="nameField" name="nameField" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="websiteField">Web Site</label>
                <input type="text" id="websiteField" name="websiteField" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="messageField">Message</label>
                <textarea name="messageField" id="messageField"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="hidden" name="submitform" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="txn_id" value="<?php echo $_POST['txn_id']?>" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
        if($errorString)
        {
            echo '<p class="error">'.$errorString.'</p>';
        }
        else if($messageString)
        {
            echo '<p class="success">'.$messageString.'</p>';
        }
        ?>

    </div>


</body>
</html>


<?php

function esc($str)
{
    global $link;

    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
            $str = stripslashes($str);

    return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($str)),$link);
}

function validateURL($str)
{
    return preg_match('/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?/i',$str);
}
?>
```

**This is the same page with the changes made to reflect email instead of website**

```
<?php

require "config.php";
require "connect.php";

if(isset($_POST['submitform']) && isset($_POST['txn_id']))
{
    $_POST['nameField'] = esc($_POST['nameField']);
    $_POST['emailField'] =  esc($_POST['emailField']);
    $_POST['messageField'] = esc($_POST['messageField']);

    $error = array();

    if(mb_strlen($_POST['nameField'],"utf-8")<2)
    {
        $error[] = 'Please fill in a valid name.';
    }

    if(mb_strlen($_POST['messageField'],"utf-8")<2)
    {
        $error[] = 'Please fill in a longer message.';
    }

    if(!validate_email($_POST['emailField']))
    {
        $error[] = 'The email you entered may be invalid! Please check same.';
    }

    $errorString = '';
    if(count($error))
    {
        $errorString = join('<br />',$error);
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("    INSERT INTO dc_comments (transaction_id, name, email, message)
                        VALUES (
                            '".esc($_POST['txn_id'])."',
                            '".$_POST['nameField']."',
                            '".$_POST['emailField']."',
                            '".$_POST['messageField']."'
                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            $messageString = '<a href="donate.php">You were added to our donor list! &raquo;</a>';
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Thank you!</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body class="thankyouPage">

<div id="main">
    <h1>Thank you for your support!</h1>
    <h2>Add your name to the donor list. </h2>

    <div class="lightSection">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="nameField">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="nameField" name="nameField" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="emailField">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="emailField" name="emailField" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="messageField">Message</label>
                <textarea name="messageField" id="messageField"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="hidden" name="submitform" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="txn_id" value="<?php echo $_POST['txn_id']?>" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
        if($errorString)
        {
            echo '<p class="error">'.$errorString.'</p>';
        }
        else if($messageString)
        {
            echo '<p class="success">'.$messageString.'</p>';
        }
        ?>

    </div>


</body>
</html>


<?php

function esc($str)
{
    global $link;

    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
            $str = stripslashes($str);

    return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($str)),$link);
}

function validate_email($str)
{
    return preg_match('.*?@.*?\...*', $str);
}
?>
```

**Why will the email not work as planned and is the approach correct?**

I am working with this [DonationScript](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/05/donation-center-php-mysql-paypal-api/thankyou.php)

Comment: As indicated, "500 Server error".  This sounds like an actual hosting error, rather than a problem with your PHP code.  Have you edited the .htaccess file at all?

Comment: Do you have access to get the contents of the error_log and put the error message here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be in your regexp, the * is an unknown modifier in your code example. Try this... Delete the validate email function completely. Then change

```
if(!validate_email($_POST['emailField']))
```

to

```
if (!filter_var($_POST['emailField'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

and see if that works for you.

Comment: Hi Austin Best, I replaced the validate function completly and that worked first time. Good work and thank you.  Does this mean that I am using a poor quality regexp for validating the email!